# Custom DateFormats mmm:ss

Tags: java

Is there a way to format a date to have mmm:ss instead of hh:mm:ss?  Basically, 7:15:28 should show up instead as 435:28 instead.

The SimpleDateFormat class does not support this format is there one that does or will I have to implement a variation myself?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll have to implement it yourself, but you should bear in mind that implementing a Formatter is not a simple task, as it has many l10n considerations.

Comment: is this as far as you know or you are sure there's no package out there that can handle this format?

Comment: @yx: there may well be packages to help you.  My answer is limited to extending the Java SE class.

Answer (score 2):

If all you want to do is format a Date into the format you specified (with no other parts of the Date included) you can just do it very simply:

```
   public String format(Date date) {      
      Calendar cal = new GregorianCalendar();
      cal.setTime(date);
      return cal.get(Calendar.HOUR) * 60 + cal.get(Calendar.MINUTE) + ":" + cal.get(Calendar.SECOND);      
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use [Joda Time](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/) to build a custom formatter. With the DateTimeFormatterBuilder class you could at least show the minutes of a day:

```
import org.joda.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import org.joda.time.format.DateTimeFormatterBuilder;

DateTimeFormatter customFormat = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
      .appendMinuteOfDay(1)
      .appendLiteral(':')
      .appendSecondOfMinute(2)
      .toFormatter();
System.out.println(customFormat.print(System.currentTimeMillis()));
```